# Update View Element from Backing-Bean with Primefaces

Tags: primefaces

is there a solution, that i can update my View from my Backing-Bean.
I have the following lines of code. I want to update my growl element from inside the loop.

```
    public void starteTransition() throws InterruptedException {
    FacesMessage m;
    RequestContext context;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100) {
        System.out.println(i);
        if (i >= 10) {
            m = new FacesMessage("10");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, m);
            context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.update("formTop:msg");

        }
        if (i >= 50) {
            m = new FacesMessage("50");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, m);
            context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.update("formTop:msg");

        }

        i++;

        Thread.sleep(500);

    }

}
```

But the update is only done when the Loop has finished.
How can i solved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it you can do it with a [p:socket](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/notify.xhtml). Create a unique channel for each user.

Also see the [user guide p. 562](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf#page=562).